# Create and assign recursively to dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read csv files from a directory and assign each to a different dataframe. I have tried to do so like this:

```
path = r'C:\Users\A\Documents\Dash'
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for file in files:
    f'df{file}' = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
```

But of course I couldn't assign to a literal, but I don't realise a way to do this. I don't really care if each dataframe is numbered differently or with the name of the csv.

Comment: You, probably, should use a dict of dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do in this way:

```
for index, file in enumerate(files):
    vars()['df'+str(index)] = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
print (df0)
print (df1)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I didn't know about vars(), this will come in handy a lot of times!

Answer (score 1):

```
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

## using map & zip:
df_list = list(map(lambda x: pd.read_csv(x, sep=","), files))  # result in list
df_dict = dict(zip(files, df_list))                            # result in dict

## using for loop:
# result in list
df_list = list()
for file in files:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, sep=','))

# result in dict
df_dict = dict()
for file in files:
    df_dict[file] = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
```

Comment: Those are nice and simple, didn't think you could do this! thanks for teaching me this many tricks